# SUM query date fusion tables doesn't work correctly

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to make SUM query from my `Fusion Tables : 1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR`.
I want to `SUM 'Jumlah Pohon'` from my tables based on 'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhr'. This is my query

```
SELECT SUM('Jumlah Pohon') 
FROM 1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR 
WHERE 'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir' >= '01/01/2013' 
      AND 'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir' <= '01/07/2014'
```

All rows record in `'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir'` is '15/06/2014' so this query should show some data.
but when i test from [Standalone Query](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql) it seems 200 OK but not show any data i want.

when i change the query to

```
SELECT SUM('Jumlah Pohon') 
FROM 1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR 
WHERE 'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir' >= '01/01/2013' 
      AND 'Tanggal Pengecekan Terakhir' <= '7/07/2014'
```

it seems the query works correctly. Why date filter query doesn't works correctly? thanks..

Comment: Perhaps the date format isn't what you expect. Looks like it might be month/day/year, not day/month/year.  [This search (from June 1, 2014 to July 1, 2013) returns results](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col2+from+1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR+where+col11+%3C%3D+'2014-07-01+00%3A00%3A00'+and+col11+%3E%3D+'2014-06-01+00%3A00%3A00'&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=-7.399138610271753&lng=110.44852267837518&t=1&z=19&l=col2&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=GEOCODABLE).

Comment: thanks for your answer @geocodezip. I set my column in fusion tables to dd/mm/yyyy, so how to filter based from my column date format dd/mm/yyyy ?